# Цикл в командной строке FOR /L

Tags: cmd

Всем привет. Подскажите, как можно сделать цикл что бы передавал по очередно файлы для aerender.exe ? Вот тут примеры есть https://helpx.adobe.com/ru/after-effects/using/automated-rendering-network-rendering.html

Пытаюсь написать вот так

```cmd
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,n) DO aerender -project "%i.aep"
```

Но ничего не запускается даже. Командная строка открыта в директории c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2017\Support Files\ и два файла проекта лежат там же 1.aep и 2.aep . Если так вообще можно сделать, позже хотел бы сделать. что бы файлы проекта искал не там же а в другой директории? И хотел бы написать батник что бы не лазить постоянно в директорию с aerender.exe, что то типо
Вот такого

```cmd
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,n) DO "c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2017\Support Files\aerender.exe" -project d:\%i.aep
```

Да, я понимаю, что это не правильно, подскажите как правильно написать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это запуск из командной строки или из bat/cmd-файла?

Comment: из командной строки

Comment: А что за "n" в цикле? там должно быть число?

Comment: имеется ввиду, неограниченное количество, или там только может быть определенное число?

Comment: там должно быть число, см. мой ответ ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы пакетно обработать файлы (и сама программа не умеет по маске), лучше поступить по другому:

- перенести (ну или скопировать) нужные файлы в пустой рабочий каталог
- и там [запустить](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) `for %%f in (*.*) do программа "%%f"`

%%f - из командного файла, или %f - если из командной строки

**Для запуска пакетной обработки**

`=== main-cmd.cmd ===`

```
@ECHO OFF
FORFILES /M *.* /C "cmd /c ProxyCMD.cmd @file
```

`=== proxy-cmd.cmd ===`

```
@ECHO OFF
::
:: Пример "прокси" для обработки одного файла
::
IF "%1"=="" GOTO Usage
GOTO Process
:Usage
ECHO Использование: ProxyCmd.cmd имя_обрабатываемого_файла
GOTO Leave
:Process
"С:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2017\Support Files\aerender.exe" -project %1
"какое-то еще действие с" %1
"и еше одно с" %1
:Leave
```

Comment: for %%f in (*.*) do "c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2017\Support Files\aerender.exe" -project "%%f"  - так правильно?

Comment: маску нужно `(*.*)`, ну а так да, вроде правильно - для запуска из командного файла

Comment: сработало, спасибо вам огромное, оказалось все намного проще чем я думал, выше я написал с маской просто отобразилось так, не знаю как в комментариях добавлять форматирование кода, совсем недавно начал использовать данный сайт :)

Comment: выделить код - в начале и в конце по обратному апострофу ``

Comment: еще есть альтернативная команда - forfiles (http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html), советую почитать

Comment: `for %f in (*.*) do "c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2017\Support Files\aerender.exe" -project "%f"`
Спасибо обязательно гляну

Comment: Я извиняюсь, хочу чуть модернизировать, но как сюда добавить еще один цикл для именования файлов?
Что бы примерно вышло вот так 
`for %f in (*.*) do "c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2017\Support Files\aerender.exe" -project "%f" -output d:\Temp\AERENDER\project_%i.mov`
Там где %i переменная из цикла для именования нескольких файлов , но куда добавлять цикл?

Comment: Цикл в цикле не получится. Нужно по другому. Сделать промежуточный командный файл - и в нем проводить всю обработку **одного** файла (т.е. рендер, переименование, перемещение). А вот в первом цикле вызывать этот промежуточный командный файл и передавать ему имя обрабатываемого файла.

Comment: Мысль я вашу понял, но как вызывать из одного батника другой? и что бы второй видел переменные из первого?

Comment: Дополнил ответ, см. выше

Comment: Не хочет, вот скрин https://i.imgur.com/3nMM8yn.png
`@ECHO OFF
FORFILES /M *.aep /C "cmd /c proxy-cmd.cmd @file`
т.к. имя файла "proxy-cmd.cmd"

Comment: Под имя файла не получится одной переменной, оно подставляет в кавычках да еще и с расширением, наверное плохая затея :( https://i.imgur.com/yzjmKs0.png
Под именования файлов нужен обычный счетчик

Comment: там в proxy-cmd.cmd похоже "C:\ ....." начинается с русского символа "эс", нужно перепроверить путь.

Answer (score 0):

```html
for %%f in (*.*) do "c:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe After Effects CC 2017\Support Files\aerender.exe" -project "%%f" -output "d:\Temp\AERENDER\project_%%~nf.mov"
```

Так намного проще будет